# Merge the information of two bands in one single "Raster layer unique value report" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

[image]I have two raster layers that occupy the same area, one for suitability (0-1) and one corresponding to energy output. I merged them keeping separated the information of both layers and now I have one raster layer with two bands.
For my goal I would want to obtain a Raster layer unique value report with the information about both:

Suitability value, Energy output value, Pixels, Area

Now I can only obtain independent Raster layer unique value report, however, I can't put them together since the maximum values of suitability may not correspond to the higher values of energy, also the same value for suitability could have different energy outputs, etc.

My ultimate goal is, with the Excel of the report, to order from max to min by suitability. Add up all the values of energy output until I reach a certain number (ex 1000). Then look what is the suitability threshold that corresponds.

Is there any way to get what I want? I'm using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question: why don't you use the unique value report on the two separate layers you have before merging them?

Comment: Because the two different unique layer reports will be ordered from minimum value to maximum. The minimum value of suitability does not have to correspond to the minimum power of energy power

Comment: Yeah, so you want to somehow connect the two datasets? This is unclear to me, you should describe a bit more in detail to make it clear, maybe adding a screenshot. Ohterwise it's difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: Yes I want to connect the datasets, so I can have the value of energy output related to suitability and see the pixels and the area that they correspond, I added some images, I hope it helps :)

Comment: Still not sure how exactly your result should look like, what exactly you expect as output. Can you shaow a few rows of examples how you want the result to look like? How many different values do you have for suitablility?